# Python seems to be automatically matching two lists, preventing me from separating them

Tags: python, list, del

```
# arranges a lists indexes from which ones have the maximum 
# value to which ones have the minimum value
def sortIndex(L):
  I = []
  original = L
  new = L
  for i in range(len(original)):
    I.append(original.index(max(new)))
    del new[I[len(I)-1]]
    print("I=",I)
    print("O=",original)
    print("N=",new)
  return I

A = [1,6,3,8,4]

print(sortIndex(A))
```

That's the code. When I run it, I get the output (note I print I, O and N after every iteration):

```
  I= [3]
  O= [1, 6, 3, 4]
  N= [1, 6, 3, 4]
  I= [3, 1]
  O= [1, 3, 4]
  N= [1, 3, 4]
  I= [3, 1, 2]
  O= [1, 3]
  N= [1, 3]
  I= [3, 1, 2, 1]
  O= [1]
  N= [1]
  I= [3, 1, 2, 1, 0]
  O= []
  N= []
  [3, 1, 2, 1, 0]
```

I don't understand why this is happening. Del seems to be deleting values from both new and original even though they are clearly separate lists. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: They're absolutely not separate lists, they're references to the same list `L`.

Comment: *they are clearly separate lists* - `original` and `new` are clearly names for the same list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they aren't actually separate lists. Both variables, `new` and `original` are pointing to the same list in memory. You can create a copy like you want with `copy.deepcopy`

```
from copy import deepcopy
original = L
new=deepcopy(original)
```

Comment: Or, you can just do 
    new = list(L)

Comment: This is true, but that doesn't work for lists of lists.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about pointers before now.

Comment: @ShahbM No problem, it was a painful lesson for me to learn the first time.

Comment: @SuperStew did op specify a list of lists?